# CakePHP - Hard time returning some data 3 level deep

Tags: cakephp

I'm trying to learn CakePHP and I'm having a hard time getting some data.
I'm working on a site tracking hockey stats (real basic stats). I have 5 tables.

- seasons (id, date_start, date_end)
- games (id, date, score_team1, score_team2, team1_id, team2_id, season_id)
- teams (id, name, color)
- players (id, first_name, last_name)
- players_teams (id, player_id, team_id)

I'm able to get the 2 teams of a game from the game view.
I'm also able to get all the players of a team from the team view.

I need help figuring out how to get all the players of a team from a game point of view.
I tried a lot of things but none seems to work. I tough that I could get all the players of a team by doing something like $game['Team1']['Players'] from my game view but it's not working. I'm trying to drill down into the players of a team from a game.
Season->Game->Team1->Players but i'm stuck at the team1 level.

Here's some of my code

/cakephp/teams -> debug($teams[1])

```
array(
    'Team' => array(
        'id' => '2',
        'name' => 'Rouge',
        'color' => 'Rouge'
    ),
    'Players' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'id' => '2',
            'first_name' => 'Player2FN',
            'last_name' => 'Player2LN',
            'PlayersTeam' => array(
                'id' => '2',
                'player_id' => '2',
                'team_id' => '2'
            )
        ),
        (int) 1 => array(
            'id' => '4',
            'first_name' => 'Player4FN',
            'last_name' => 'Player4LN',
            'PlayersTeam' => array(
                'id' => '4',
                'player_id' => '4',
                'team_id' => '2'
            )
        )
    )
)
```

But from the game detail view I get this -> debug($game) :

```
array(
    'Game' => array(
        'id' => '2',
        'date' => '2012-09-16 19:30:00',
        'score_team1' => '8',
        'score_team2' => '4',
        'team1_id' => '2',
        'team2_id' => '1',
        'season_id' => '1'
    ),
    'Team1' => array(
        'id' => '2',
        'name' => 'Rouge',
        'color' => 'Rouge'
    ),
    'Team2' => array(
        'id' => '1',
        'name' => 'Bleu',
        'color' => 'Bleu'
    ),
    'Season' => array(
        'id' => '1',
        'date_start' => '2012-09-09',
        'date_end' => '2013-04-07'
    )
)
```

I'm pretty sure it's a model problem so here's both my Team and game model

```
<?php
    class Game extends AppModel {
        public $name = 'Game';
        public $belongsTo = array(
            'Season',
            'Team1' => array (
                'className' => 'Team',
                'foreignKey' => 'team1_id'
            ),
            'Team2' => array (
                'className' => 'Team',
                'foreignKey' => 'team2_id'
            )
        );
    }
?>

<?php
    class Team extends AppModel {
        public $name = 'Team';
        public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
            'Players' =>
                array(
                    'className'              => 'Player',
                    'joinTable'              => 'players_teams',
                    'foreignKey'             => 'team_id',
                    'associationForeignKey'  => 'id'
                )
        );
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
   $this->Game->recursive=2; 
   $this->Game->find('all');
```

Comment: I understand this works, but wouldn't it be inefficient for large volumes of data? Would the Contain behavior be better?

Comment: Yes. It depends how your database is set up, but if the model are a bit complicated, it's a performance drain. I always try to implement contain, but recursive has the big advantage of being a one liner. Nice for quick dev, small data, simple models. In the end I believe that the contain will be necessary, but there it can be implemented when Pureconstant is more familiar with the framwork.